# Нужны туториалы

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет.
Прошу вас помочь найти туториалы по созданию сайта на php + mysql. 
Мне нужно сделать новостной сайт.
Обращаюсь не потому что не могу найти их, просто может вы знаете нормальный источник где всё нормально расписано.

Answer (score 1):

Есть хорошая книжеца автор Николай Прохоренок называется "HTML, JavaScript, PHP и MySQL. Джентльменский набор Web-мастера" в торрентах можно найти, все очень доходчиво описано, с примерами.

Answer (score 1):

вам нужен друпал, а не php, mysql, если уже **нужно сделать новостной сайт**
А вот если **нужно научиться сделать сайт**, то да - php, mysql. 
php - книга Колисниченко
mysql - книга Поля Дюбуа.

Answer (score 0):

Что вы имеете ввиду под туториалами?

Есть отличные сайты-справочники по написанным вами технологиям, например [php.su](http://php.su/).
Если вам нужны уроки, могу посоветовать посмотреть блог [Андрея Морковина](http://www.sdelaysite.com/).

Comment: Уроки, примеры и т.п.